# Table Required Methods - TableRequiredMethods autocomplete

Tags: ios, xcode

I was watching tutorial videos and find interesting function in one of them. [You can see it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlZ21tJFmJY) on 6:44 .

When he starts to write table there's an autocomplete to add necessary methods for protocols he use. How can i add same feature to my Xcode? (i'm using 6.2)

Comment: Ok, i got it. That was a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, Just write whatever methods you want. In case of video, its tableview methods, once added in source file, select the methods what you want to have like a `snippet of Xcode`. Now drag them into code snippet library which is shown in the attached image. Here enter sometime for this code snippet. From next time you just enter your snipper name and click enter, those methods will be added in source file like as shown in video.[image: Create snippet]

Comment: Yeah, i know. But the question is - how to insert this two necessary for `<UITableViewDataSource>` protocol methods by one click like in video. But now i think that it was a snippets.

Answer (score 0):

while typing click together control + space....

```
e.g. override func tableView ...
```

then use it and it will show options